# Undefined .data section for ASM

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, irvine32

I got an error when I tried to complier this ASM

```
Write an assembly program to implement the following. 
while X > 0
if  X != 3 AND (X > A OR X <B)
X = X –2
else
X = X –1
end while
```

Use short-circuit evaluation-Assume that A, B, and X are 16-bit signed integers variables-Assume that A=9, B=8, and X=11

I got .code area but am I missing .data?

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
     ; declare variables here
     X WORD ?

.code
main proc
     ; write your code here
     mov eax, X
     beginwhile:
     cmp eax, 0
     jng endwhile
     mov ebx,A
     mov ecx,B
     cmp X,3
     jne L1
     jmp L3
     jmp endwhile
L1:  
    cmp X, ebx
    jl L2
    cmp X,ecx
    jg L2
    jmp L3
    jmp endwhile
L2:
    mov X, X-2
    jmp endwhile
L3:
    mov X, X-1
    jmp endwhile
    endwhile:
    mov X, eax

    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: What is the error? PS: `WORD` doesn't make much sense, you probably wanted `DWORD` or `DD`.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error A2070 invalid instruction operands  
Error A2070 invalid instruction operands  
Error A2022 instruction operands must be the same size  
Error A2006 undefined symbol : A  
Error A2006 undefined symbol : B  
Error A2022 instruction operands must be the same size  
Error A2022 instruction operands must be the same size 
Error A2022 instruction operands must be the same size

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55754959/edit) link to add new information into your question. Also mark the linkes for easier referencing. Anyway, the errors are pretty clear. For example, you only defined `X` and not `A` or `B`.

Comment: Also, your assignment says to use 16 bit integers but you use 32. So `WORD` is actually okay for `X` but your code is wrong, and you are of course still missing `A` and `B`. Not to mention you have not initialized them to the given values. `mov X, X-2` is just invalid, you can't do that directly.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged with Visual Studio, I would assume MASM (ML.EXE) is being used, in which case the dot directives could be used, but I'm not sure this would be the goal of the assignment. The dot directive operators need to be translatable to actual instructions, so memory to memory compares aren't allowed.

However, the title and the question asks about uninitialized data section, which is .data?, and shown in this example.

```
        .data?
;                   ;for signed word, use sword instead of word
A       word    ?
B       word    ?
X       word    ?

        .code
;       ...    
        mov     ax,A
        mov     bx,B
        .while  (X > 0)
          .if     (X != 3) && (X > ax || X < bx)
            sub     X,2
          .else
            sub     X,1
          .endif
        .endw
;       ...
```